# Help with transform.lookat and camera?

Tags: unity, transformation

```
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
transform.LookAt(mousePos);
```

This will actually make the camera follow the mouse, but it goes crazy, the camera seems to spin in circles rapidly : here is actually a gif of what is happening. https://gyazo.com/952da6c28e644b7b0e6500a597b6804e/preview Could anyone help me figure how how to fix it?

Comment: lol @DMGregory that's the same person

Comment: @Sidar Yes, it is. And when the same user posts a question twice, it's still a duplicate.

Comment: No one is disputing that, I just find the use of "possible" funny. Also he edited that post to make it sound like this one. @BondyeLwa you should remove that other post.

Answer (score 0):

ScreenToWorldPoint is a point in 3D space that's basically at the cameras position. That's why it's flipping out.

try something like

```
mousepos += (camera.transform.forward * 100);
```

to actually get the point further away from the camera.

The 100 here is arbitrary.

Edit:

This will not make the camera orbit if that's what you want. Check the Unity Standard Assets for prescripted camera scripts.

Comment: Sorry I've been really busy and just got back to this project. Would I add this line in to my fixed update and get rid of the line that I originally posted?

Comment: Tried to edit first comment with: I figure I still need to define mousepos, so i kept that line and commented out my second line from op, then added your line in instead. I got an error on the line you posted though saying that " Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: That would be `mousepos += (camera.transform.forward * 100);` you have to add it to mousepos. But again I don't think this is what you're looking for if you want an orbital camera?

Comment: I really just want my character to be able to turn and the camera to follow behind him.

Comment: As I said import the Standard Assets package that contains Camera scripts and you're set.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-InstallStandardAssets.html